# Getting 405 (Method not allowed) when uploading images with CKFinder

Tags: ckeditor, http-status-code-405, ckfinder

Until yesterday, I was able to use CKFinder with CKEditor 4 to upload images to the server and add them to the inline CKEditor.

Now, all of a sudden, I'm getting a 405 (Method not allowed) error when trying to upload an image. CKFinder itself is returning "Error 10: Invalid command". This happens even if I re-upload images that I uploaded before.

I am able to see the contents of userfiles in CKFinder, so it's not a matter of a wrong directory. Also, I've tried adding

**config.filebrowserUploadMethod = 'form'**

to config.js, but my browser console's Network tab still shows the outgoing request as 'xhr'. Don't know if that's relevant.

Can anyone help? Again, this worked fine yesterday, I have no idea what has changed.

Here's the network tab output for the failed upload:

[image: Here's the network tab output for the failed upload]

Comment: If CKFinder was working yesterday but doesn't today, something had to be changed. CKFinder couldn’t stop working just like that. The error HTTP 405 is not about fomr/xhr upload method but about GET/POST/HEAD etc. Please open Network tab browser dev-tools (best Firefox or Chrome) and check what type of the request is being made to server when you try to upload a file. You can paste it here or if you are using PHP version compare it with DEMO requests  - https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/demo/ckfinder3/samples/

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the Network tab output for the failed upload request. Seems to be a GET.

Comment: As you probably know, this should be sent through POST. Please check your .htaccess file for possible redirects. Also when looking through the network i have found an old link mentioning some plugin and framework specific feature like presence trailing stash forcing change from POST to GET - https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/450. You could look for something similar in your setup. One thing for sure this is not CKFinder problem.